# How to install oci.h header file in redhat 7.6

Tags: linux

I want to install the **oci.h** header file for proc in my **linux server redhat 7.6v**,Please provide the package name or steps?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide more details on what you are doing. You probably need not only the header files but also the corresponding import libraries.

Comment: Hi, Actually I have new linux server , I have to install g++ compiler and oracle client packages and supported files  for proc files compilation also but i have done those all but oci.h header file is not available ,so i am not sure how i can install the oci.h header file for proc file compilation(EX:CLOB,BLOB,oracle File handling using in proc file purpose only).

Comment: g++ : `# yum install gcc-c++`. ... **oci.h** : ftp://ftp.pbone.net/mirror/ftp5.gwdg.de/pub/opensuse/repositories/home:/davidnichols/CentOS_7/x86_64/oracle-instantclient-devel-12.2.0.1.0-19.3.x86_64.rpm → oracle-instantclient-devel-12.2.0.1.0-19.3.x86_64.rpm : Depends on `libclntsh.so.12.1()(64bit), oracle-instantclient = 12.2.0.1.0`.